# Laravel/Livewire Validation - String is failing when null in dev, but passing fine in production

Tags: laravel, validation, development-environment, production-environment, laravel-livewire

I have some validation rules applied to a model using the nested syntax:

```
protected $rules = ['model.notes' => 'string'];
```

The notes property has no default value, so when the model is first created it defaults to null.

When the validator runs, given no input, in the dev environment this rule fails, even though the property is not required. However, in the production environment it passes just fine without any errors.

I am aware that I could add the nullable rule to allow the validation to pass with a null value. Equally I can set the default value on the model to an empty string which would also allow the  validator to pass. And finally, there is a question over whether this rule is even required given anything entered in the text box will be a string regardless...

But my main concern is why the different behaviours between environments? If it fails in dev then I want it to fail in production, too!

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should be like:

```
protected $rules = ['model.notes' => 'nullable|string'];
```